# Select rows with specific conditions AND apply function

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to double out values to only rows with 'hesc'. For example, 4th rows with 5.929771 is to be 11.859542(5.929771*2).

filter() function in dplyr package is not of helpful at all cause I do not want the extract some values to make a new dataframe.

[dataframe] 22x3

```
   expr_value      cell_type 
1  5.345618       fibroblast 
2  5.195871       fibroblast 
3  5.247274       fibroblast 
4  5.929771          hesc 
5  5.873096          hesc 
6  5.665857          hesc 
7  6.791656          hips 
8  7.133673          hips 
9  7.574058          hips 
10 7.208041          hips 
11 7.402100          hips 
12 7.167792          hips 
13 7.156971          hips 
14 7.197543          hips 
15 7.035404          hesc 
16 7.269474          hesc 
17 6.715059          hesc 
18 7.434339          hips 
19 6.997586          hips 
20 7.619770          hips 
21 7.490749          hips
```

In this case, how to apply simple arithmetic to cerntain rows?
I tried to write a code like "if(dataframe$cell_type ="hesc") ....".
guessed there'll be a better way.

already know that filter() in dplyr can be used to extract certain rows that I only concerns, but it just give me a new dataframe if I understand correctly. What I want to do is, find certain rows in dataframe and then apply some arithmetic to the values right away.

Comment: `df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(expr_value = ifelse(cell_type == "hesc", expr_value * 2, expr_value)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `grep` to find `cell_type1` with `"hesc"` and then multiply them by 2

```
inds <- grep("hesc", df$cell_type1)
df$expr_value[inds] <- df$expr_value[inds] * 2
```

Or without intermediate variable

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%  mutate(expr_value = expr_value * c(1, 2)[grepl("hesc", cell_type1) + 1])

#   expr_value  cell_type1
#1    5.345618 fibroblast2
#2    5.195871 fibroblast3
#3    5.247274 fibroblast4
#4   11.859542       hesc5
#5   11.746192       hesc6
#6   11.331714       hesc7
#7    6.791656       hips8
#8    7.133673       hips9
#9    7.574058      hips10
#....
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(expr_value = c(5.345618, 5.195871, 5.247274, 5.929771, 
5.873096, 5.665857, 6.791656, 7.133673, 7.574058, 7.208041, 7.4021, 
7.167792, 7.156971, 7.197543, 7.035404, 7.269474, 6.715059, 7.434339, 
6.997586, 7.61977, 7.490749), cell_type1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 20L, 21L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 7L), .Label = c("fibroblast2", "fibroblast3", 
"fibroblast4", "hesc5", "hesc6", "hesc7", "hips", "hips10", "hips11", 
"hips12", "hips13", "hips14", "hips15", "hips16", "hips17", "hips18", 
"hips19", "hips20", "hips21", "hips8", "hips9"), class = "factor")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -21L))
```

Comment: thankyou for the comments but is there any other way to do this without making another dataframe?

Comment: @Frank.lee What do you mean by another dataframe ? You can assign this to same dataframe, `df <- df %>%  mutate(expr_value = expr_value * c(1, 2)[grepl("hesc", cell_type1) + 1])`

Comment: Nevermind, Ronak Shah. I'm stupid and it worked. appreciate.. (don't know how to call your name coloring your name blue.)

Comment: say for example there is more columns like 'cell_type', how do i add conditions?
I've tested out || operations but it didn't work. grep(("cell_type" || "model_type"), grep(("cell_type" or "model_type")

Comment: and although it totally worked the way i wanted, i still don't get how it does especially for "c(1, 2)[grepl("hesc", cell_type1) + 1]" (I understands first way you wrote, though)

Comment: @Frank.lee Basically, it is vector indexing where a value with "hesc" is multiplied by 2 and rest all with 1. Also if you have an exact match compare it with `==` instead. `df %>%  mutate(expr_value = expr_value * c(1, 2)[(cell_type1 == "hesc") + 1])`

Answer (score 1):

You can as well do in the following way:

1. Subset `expr_value` where `cell_type1 =="hesc"`

```r
df[df$cell_type1 =="hesc",]["expr_value"]
#    expr_value
#4   5.929771
#5   5.873096
#6   5.665857
```

2. Multiply the same by the desired value (`2`)

```r
df[df$cell_type1 =="hesc",]["expr_value"] *2
```

3. Use the above two concepts to do an in place assignment using a one liner as follows.

```r
df[df$cell_type1 =="hesc",]["expr_value"] <- df[df$cell_type1 =="hesc",]["expr_value"]  *2
```

The above two (`1` & `2`) are explanation. All you need to do is `3`.

## data

```r
df <- structure(list(expr_value = c(5.345618, 5.195871, 5.247274, 5.929771, 
5.873096, 5.665857, 6.791656, 7.133673, 7.574058, 7.208041, 7.4021, 
7.167792, 7.156971, 7.197543, 7.035404, 7.269474, 6.715059, 7.434339, 
6.997586, 7.61977, 7.490749), cell_type1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 20L, 21L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 7L), .Label = c("fibroblast", "fibroblast", 
"fibroblast", "hesc", "hesc", "hesc", "hips", "hips", "hips", 
"hips", "hips", "hips", "hips", "hips", "hips", "hips", "hips", 
"hips", "hips", "hips", "hips"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-21L))
```

## Note

If there are `NA`s in your column you can constrain the in place assignment in the following way

```r
df[!is.na(df$cell_type1) & df$cell_type1 =="hesc",]["expr_value"] <- df[!is.na(df$cell_type1) & df$cell_type1 =="hesc",]["expr_value"] *2

#   expr_value
#4   11.85954
#5   11.74619
#6   11.33171
```